# How to use with limit data in DynamoDB query in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pycharm, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to get data from DynamoDB table by chunk, 2 values every time.
I don't found a sample code for python, tried to translate from c# and the code isn't working.
Before I added the limit and the ExclusiveStartKey to the query I got the data from AWS.
Can somebody help please?

`name`&`source` are parameters I provide.

This is my code

```
    while True:
        lastKeyEvaluated = null;
        sourceTable = dynamodb.Table (source)
        response = sourceTable.query (
            IndexName="Name-index",
            KeyConditionExpression=Key ('Name').eq (name),
            Limit = 1,
            ExclusiveStartKey = lastKeyEvaluated,
        )
        lastKeyEvaluated = response['LastEvaluatedKey'];
        print ("get data passed sucssesfully")
        print (response)
        if lastKeyEvaluated == null and lastKeyEvaluated.Count is 0:
            break
        return response
```

Comment: Could you share the error(s) that you are getting? Also, make sure to format your code properly as there are a lot of spaces in places where they shouldn't be.
Finally, make sure to check the documentation of the Python AWS SDK: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your question, it's possible that your code stopped working when you added the "lastKeyEvaluated".

First of all, in Python you don't use a semicolon to end a statement, that's one problem.
Another problem is that you're declaring your "lastKeyEvaluated" variable with a null value. Python works with None instead of null.

Finally, if you review the documentation regarding boto3, you'll see that the ExclusiveStartKey accepts a dictionary as a value, so that will raise another error.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query